# Excel vba: Refresh page format without saving

Tags: vba, excel

I have a vba code that will create a new workbook from an existing sheet then edit the format on this new sheet to remove superfluous information and make it more friendly to print. (I simply move/delete/create cells, rows and columns)

If I do not save and I try to print this new sheet with the option *'fit all column to one page'* it would use for all column size the original column size of the sheet.

If I save however it would update the column size to the actual edited size.

Is there a way to refresh page format without saving?

**Edit:** Here is a very compact version of the code:

```
Sub SmallPsetup()
Dim OrderBook As Workbook
Dim RefBook As Workbook
Set RefBook = Application.ActiveWorkbook
Set OrderBook = Workbooks.Add
' Copy sheet
RefBook.Sheets("MySheet").Copy Before:=OrderBook.Sheets(1)
' Remove superfluous/incomplete information
ActiveSheet.Columns("Q:AZ").Delete
End Sub
```

Comment: Could you try `ActiveSheet.UsedRange`? It will force Excel to recal the `UsedRange` ([related post](https://superuser.com/a/810950/756913))

Comment: @Prisoner: This is just what I needed.

Comment: @Jean-PierreOosthuizen: in my code I indeed set `ScreenUpdating` to `False` then later to `True` but the command does not seems to have impact on this topic I also tried to move `ActiveSheet.UsedRange` before `Application.ScreenUpdating = True` this would still refresh the column width properly.

Comment: Jonathan good stuff,  I am glad @Prisoner could assist you in getting your code working.